# How do I use up my canned tomato paste?

Tags: culinary-uses, tomatoes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you do with left over tomato paste?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6636/what-do-you-do-with-left-over-tomato-paste)

I have many cans of tomato paste, and I just want to get some ideas about how to use them up.

Comment: Hi Pollyanna, welcome to Seasoned Advice!  You should find the answers you're looking for in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use tomato paste infrequently, then you could do as I do: when opening a can (typically only to use a tablespoon full for a recipe), I divide the remainder of the can into tablespoon-sized portions, wrap them individually in plastic wrap, and freeze them until required.

Answer (score 0):

To store tomato paste..

Tomato paste can be stored in fridge for a long time as Doug pointed out. You can try to use the ice cube trays and spread it out into it, then freeze it and take it out and put it into resealable ziplock bags.

Easy recipe concerning tomato pastes..

1/ Spread on french bread, Add plenty of cheese, Sprinkle herbs mix on (Basil comes to mind) and you have a mini pizza
2/ Mix olive oil (4 tablespoon) : Tomato paste (2 tablespoon) : Minced garlic (2 teaspoon) together in that proportion. Stir-fry until garlic become golden brown. Then store in fridge. Toss with spaghetti (salted with kosher salt when cooked) when needed. 
3/ Pizza!!!!!!!